# Interface returning null in java

Tags: java

I am trying to get information from my AsyncHttpClient in my Android app, and I need to use an interface to set the variable so I can use it in my main method. However, when I run `System.out.println(PostResponse);`, I am getting `null`.

I don't understand why, because if I put the line in my `callback()` method, I get the values.

From my main method:

```
try {
    JSONArray PostResponse = PerformPostRequest(new OnJSONResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public JSONArray onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONArray response) {
            System.out.println("Response: " + response);  //This is returning the correct value

            return response;
        }
    }, PostData);

    System.out.println("Useable: " + PostResponse); //This is returning null.
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The interface:

```
public interface OnJSONResponseCallback {
    public JSONArray onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONArray response);
}
```

The AsyncHttpClient:

```
public JSONArray PerformPostRequest(final OnJSONResponseCallback callback, JSONObject PostData) {
    //To authenticate against the API we need the user's credentials
    String Email = getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString("Email","");
    String Password = getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString("Password","");

    final JSONArray[] ResponseStorage = new JSONArray[1];

    //Add the credentials to post data
    try{
        PostData.put("email", Email);
        PostData.put("password", Password);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Then we need to put the post data into request parameters so we can send them in the call.
    RequestParams RequestParameters = new RequestParams();
    RequestParameters.put("data", PostData);

    //This is the client we will use to make the request.
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.post(AppHost + "MyMeetings.php", RequestParameters, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String ResponseString = new String(responseBody);
                ResponseStorage[0] = new JSONArray(ResponseString);
                System.out.println(ResponseStorage[0] + "<=============");  //Returns with the array
                callback.onJSONResponse(true, ResponseStorage[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "JSONException on success: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error: " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "JSONException on failure: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });

    JSONArray ResponseArray = new JSONArray();

    try{
        System.out.println(ResponseStorage[0] + "<==============="); //Returning null?
        ResponseArray = ResponseStorage[0];
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("ResponseArray" + ResponseArray); //Returns null
    return ResponseArray;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? I think it is something to do with my call in the main method.

### Edit:

1) I tried to return the `ResponseArray` (set in onsuccess) but I can't return it from onsuccess because it is public void. When I tried to change it to public JSONArray, I get an incompatible return type error.

2) I have updated the method so it returns something other than null, however, it still returns as null, even when I am printing it inside the AsyncHttp.

Comment: my guess, you are trying to process your response before it is actually returned.

Comment: The last line of `PerformPostRequest` is `return null;`.

Comment: It returns `null` because you told it to. There is only one `return` statement, and it returns `null`.

Comment: I tried to return the `ResponseArray` (set in onsuccess) but I can't return it from onsuccess because it is public void. When I tried to change it to public JSONArray, I get an incompatible return type error.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea behind the asynchronous calls is that:

- the asynchronous method call (in your case `PerformPostRequest`) returns immediately and does *not* return the expected result - instead it returns either just an accept confirmation or an object from which you can sometimes in the future get the result (such as an instance of a `Future`)
- you provide the method a callback interface (in your case `OnJSONResponseCallback`) or the method returns an instance of a callback interface, and you check regularly if there is already a result ready.

You should not expect that the asynchronous method returns the result immediately, this is exactly the *opposite* of asynchronous call.

Here is the rough idea expressed by pictures. It is just an overall picture of the whole idea, so the implementation details may be quite different!

[image: Synchronous method call]

[image: Asynchronous method call - A]

[image: Asynchronous method call - B]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set the variable from the `PerformPostRequest()`, which by default does not get called. At the top of my class, I set a

```
public JSONArray[] PostResponse = new JSONArray[1];
```

and updated the bit where I was calling the post request to the following:

```
//Make a post request
try {
    JSONObject PostData = new JSONObject();
    PostData.put("action","test");
    PerformPostRequest(new OnJSONResponseCallback(){
        @Override
        public JSONArray onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONArray response) {
            PostResponse[0] = response;
            System.out.println(PostResponse[0]); //This will be replaced by calling the method I want to call.
            return PostResponse[0];
        }
    }, PostData);
    System.out.println(PostResponse[0]);
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```